# How to use "onclickserver"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had some code and I tested the onserverclick event - I have applied it to an hyperlink and ran some tests.
test 1 was changing a label from one text to another: this test worked.
test 2 was doing it with some code involved - this one wasn`t a successful one.
here is the important part of my html code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Regular"></asp:Label>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4"  >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAlbumID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <a href="#" id="test" runat="server" onserverclick="Unnamed_ServerClick">
                <img id="ibShowAlbums"
                src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "coverPhoto") %>'
                class="album" />
            </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

This is the important part of my code behind:

```
protected void Unnamed_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "inside";
        HyperLink link = (HyperLink)sender;
        DataListItem item = (DataListItem)link.NamingContainer;

        Label l = item.FindControl("lblAlbumID") as Label;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(l.Text);

        Label1.Text = id.ToString();
    }
```

The label now, in this state still shows its default string - but when there is no more code involved (only changing the text) - it works.

I would love to get some help here please.

Comment: There is a difference between anchor tag and Hyperlink control. You are converting a normal HTML control (not tag) as a Hyperlink control of Asp.Net. Maybe the line `HyperLink link = (HyperLink)sender;` is throwing an exception or it is null. Please debug.

Comment: @vivek I thought it was the problem - but which variable should I use for anchor tag if not HyperLink?

Comment: you can use `HtmlAnchor ` in place of `Hyperlink`. check this link 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ff86hxd(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @vivek thanks for the answer.
But I dont have HtmlAnchor.
When I am trying to write it it just doesnt exists

Comment: Try a LinkButton.